# Grids are not getting displayed in my JUPYTER notebook

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid

Using the facetgrid , the grids are not getting displayed . just the histogram is displayed .

[image: grids are not displayed]

Comment: that's the standard behaviour, do you want the grid showing up? or the gray background or both?

Comment: i want to display them both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to set_style('darkgrid')

Answer (score 1):

Try to call the following before plotting

```
sns.set()
```